# Can't understand proof of fundamental theorem of symmetric polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, proof-explanation, symmetric-polynomials

I'm reading through *Introduction to Abstract Algebra* 4th edition by Nicholson, and I'm having trouble understanding the proof for the fundamental theorem of symmetric polynomials in section 4.5 (Never before in reading this book have I had such a hard time understanding a proof, and this is only paragraph 1 of 7!! Normally after a minute things would click when something's not clear when I'm reading a proof, but this isn't happening here.). In particular I've been stuck on the first paragraph for like 30 minutes yet the final few sentences are not very clear.

> Let $g = g(x_1, \dots, x_n) \neq 0$ be symmetric. If $k_1, \dots, k_m$ are the (distinct) integers that occur as degrees of monomials in $f$, then $g = g_1 + \cdots + g_m$, where $g_i$ is homogeneous of degree $k_i$ for each $i$. Given $\sigma \in S$, and a monomial $h(x_1, \dots, x_n)$, the fact that $h(x_1, \dots, x_n)$ and $h(x_{\sigma 1}, \dots, x_{\sigma n})$ have the same degree shows that each $g_i$ is itself symmetric. Hence, we may assume that $g$ is homogeneous.

Ok, I'm mainly confused with the conclusions the author is drawing here, and here are my two questions:

1. How did the author conclude that each $g_i$ is symmetric?
2. How does the fact that $g$ is homogeneous follow from this fact?

Thanks!

**And please don't explain at the graduate level. I'm not a graduate. There's a reason I'm reading an introductory book. This has happened numerous times so I'm just putting this here.**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let's take a look at a concrete example, say $g(x, y) = x + y + xy$. This is a symmetric polynomial, in fact it's the sum of a homogeneous symmetric polynomial $x + y$ of degree $1$ and another homogeneous symmetric polynomial $xy$ of degree $2$. You might wonder: is it always true that a symmetric polynomial is a sum of homogeneous symmetric polynomials?

The answer is yes. The reason is that permuting the variables preserves degree: permuting the variables in a degree $k$ monomial produces another degree $k$ monomial. Above permuting $x$ produces $y$ (degree $1$) and permuting $xy$ produces itself (degree $2$). So the action of permuting variables operates in each degree "independently" (there's a more formal way to say this in terms of direct sums but I'll avoid it); the permutation actions in different degrees don't interact. This means that a polynomial is symmetric iff its degree $k$ part is symmetric for each $k$, which means that a symmetric polynomial must be a sum of homogeneous symmetric polynomials. You could write this out in a lot more detail but it's pretty tedious.

The conclusion is not that $g$ is homogeneous; it is that to prove the fundamental theorem of symmetric polynomials it suffices to prove it for homogeneous symmetric polynomials, because every symmetric polynomial is a sum of homogeneous symmetric polynomials. The last step is a [WLOG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Without_loss_of_generality) assumption, reducing from the general case to the homogeneous case.

Comment: Thanks for this thorough response! I forgot my best friend “concrete examples” was there lol